# bootstrap navbar not sizing properly when dropdowns open when viewport is narrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im working with Twitter Bootstrap 3. Im looking at using the Navbar component - however it seams to me like its not working properly - even on the Bootstrap website !

When you collapse the view-port down and the nav collapses, if you click on the nav to open it... Once open, if you click the "dropdown" - it opens too, however the window does not size properly, and the links at the end of the list end up getting chopped off !

You can see the example on the Bootstrap site behaving like this:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Im using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 on the mac also does the same thing in Safari 7.0

Has anyone experienced this or got a solution ?

Comment: I see - it does have a scroll bar - however thats pretty poor UI design, id prefer to make the entire thing be visible when a dropdown is opened... Any idea's on the CSS to make that happen ?

Answer (score 0):

It has a scroll-bar, did you observed it? if I understood your question properly.